# integral with pdf of a gaussian

Tags: integration, normal-distribution

$$ I = \int_{0}^{\infty} x \phi(x) dx $$

where $\phi(x)$ is the pdf of a normal distribution.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381161/how-to-do-this-integral-int-0-infty-int-0-infty-x-y-phix-y-dx?rq=1) I read that:

If $X = \mu + \sigma U$ with $U$ a std normal,

$$ I = E[\mu + \sigma U; mu + \sigma U > 0] = \mu P[U > -\mu /\sigma] +
\sigma E[U; U > - \mu / \sigma]$$

thus

$$ I = \mu \Psi(\frac{\mu}{\sigma}) + \sigma \Phi(\frac{\mu}{\sigma})$$

where $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ are the PDF and CDF of a std normal.

However, I don't understand why
$ E[U; U > - \mu / \sigma]$ leads to the cumulative distribution. If we define $c=-\mu/\sigma$:
$$ f_{X | X > c} = \frac{P(X \in dx)}{P(X>c)}$$
we get to:

$$E[U | U > c] = \int_c^{\infty} x \frac{\Phi(x)}{1-\Psi(c)} dx $$

$$ = \bigg[ \frac{1}{1-\Psi(c)} x\Psi(x) \bigg]_0^\infty - \int_c^\infty\Psi(x) dx $$

which I can't simplify further besides saying:

$$ x \Psi(x) = - \Phi(x) $$

---

Actually, using $\Phi' = -x \Phi$ (thanks @copper.hat)

$$ E[U|U>c] = \frac{1}{1 - \Psi(c)} \Phi(c) $$

which is still different than the original answer.

Comment: Surely $\phi'(x) = -x \phi(x)$? Then $\int_a^b x \phi(x)dx = \phi(a)-\phi(b)$?

Comment: "Solving the integral by parts does not help" Really? How so? Could you be more specific about what you did?

Comment: I have improved on my question. Originally I thought that there would have been a pre-backed schoolbook solution to that integral.

Comment: Are you using $\Phi$ for $\varphi$ and $\Psi$ for $\Phi$ just for kicks?

Comment: I am sorry, I made a mess with the notation. Now I reverted to the original notation where $\Psi$ is the CDF.

Comment: I don't understand how this question is "missing context or other details". What am I not seeing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** define $Q(x) = x^2/2$.

$$x\phi(x) = \frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}}Q'(x)\exp(-Q(x))
$$

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, so I feel it deserves +1 :-)